# Resource not found error in grails for loading images from a folder

Tags: image, grails, groovy, gsp

I am building a store. In the store images will be listed (Elastislide) as category. Clicking on each image will lead another page with its description. So I have a set of images in each category, for example appstore/uploads/images/category1. My aim is to show all the images in the category1 folder as an elstislide list.

Following is my action in controller appstore

```
def store() {
    def webRootDir = request.getContextPath()
    def serverUploadPath="uploads"
    def imagePath="Image"
    def imagesFolder = webRootDir + "/" + serverUploadPath +  "/" +imagePath+"/"+"category1"
    def imageList1 = new File(imagesFolder).list()
    def imageList = Arrays.asList(imageList1)

    println imageList

    [imageList: imageList]
}
```

And in my store gsp page

```
<h2>category1</h2>
<ul class="elastislide-list">
    <g:each in="${imageList}" var="image">
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:">
                <img src="${resource(dir: '/appstore/uploads/Image/category1', file: image)}" alt="image01"/>
            </a>
            <br>amma
        </li>
    </g:each>
</ul>
```

In the store page no image is loaded, and  I am getting the following error..

```
| Error 2014-04-30 16:00:26,359 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /RITE/uploads/Image/category1/1.jpg
| Error 2014-04-30 16:00:26,361 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /RITE/uploads/Image/category1/10.jpg
| Error 2014-04-30 16:00:26,362 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /RITE/uploads/Image/category1/11.jpg
| Error 2014-04-30 16:00:26,364 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /RITE/uploads/Image/category1/12.jpg
| Error 2014-04-30 16:00:26,366 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /RITE/uploads/Image/category1/13.jpg
| Error 2014-04-30 16:00:26,368 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /RITE/uploads/Image/category1/14.jpg
| Error 2014-04-30 16:00:26,370 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  -
```

Comment: I assume going to `/RITE/uploads/Image/category1/10.jpg` in your browser shows the image?

Comment: What should the URL be to show that image?  I believe this is your problem ;-)

Comment: But the url that I had given is correct..

Comment: I can't see `appstore` in the path in your `store` method... But it's in the `resource` call in the gsp...